# INTERSECT multiple subqueries in MS-Access (without INTERSECT keyword)

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, ms-jet-ace

I need to intersect multiple subqueries in MS Access. Unfortunately, Access-SQL does not support the INTERSECT keyword. I understand, how we can use INNER JOIN of two tables to get the intersection we want. But how can I programmatically create a query that will make the intersection of N subqueries?

To be more specific: I have a table of Employees and a table of Specializations. Each employee can have multiple specializations which means there's a many to many relationship between Employees and Specializations represented by an additional table which contains the ids of employees and specializations, nothing complicated.

Now let's say that I want a list of employees, all of which have all of the specializations specified somewhere. In any other SQL engine I would simply create a list of subqueries and used the INTERSECTION keyword to "join" these subqueries together creating something like:

```
SELECT * FROM ( 
        (SELECT id, first_name, last_name FROM Employees JOIN Emp_spec 
            ON Employee.id = Emp_spec.spec_id WHERE Emp_spec.spec_id=x_1 )
        INTERSECT 
        ... 
        INTERSECT
        (SELECT id, first_name, last_name FROM Employees JOIN Emp_spec 
            ON Employee.id = Emp_spec.spec_id WHERE Emp_spec.spec_id=x_n )
);
```

, where x_1,...,x_n represent some ids corresponding to some specializations. This query returns a set of employees, all of which have all the specializations x_1,...,x_n. So how do I create such query in Access without the INTERSECT keyword. I've been trying to write the equivalent query with INNER JOIN but I can't seem to succeed.

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT Employees.*
    FROM Employees 
    INNER JOIN Emp_spec ON Employees.ID = Emp_spec.Employee_ID
    WHERE (((Emp_spec.Spec_ID) In (1,3)));

Comment: That assumes your linking table has both a [Employee_ID] and a [Spec_ID]. It also assumes the [Spec_id] is stored as a number and not text. If text, they will need to be in single quotes.

Comment: Nope, that's not it. Your returns a set of employees where each employee has at least one of the desired specializations. However, I want all the employees to have all the selected specializations. Btw, your select does the same thing as if you used UNION instead of INTERSECT in my query above.

Comment: Ah, I did not understand the result had to have ALL of the chosen specializations. `SELECT DISTINCT Employees.*
FROM (Employees INNER JOIN Emp_spec ON Employees.ID = Emp_spec.Employee_ID) 
INNER JOIN Emp_spec AS Emp_spec_1 ON Employees.ID = Emp_spec_1.Employee_ID
WHERE (((Emp_spec.Spec_ID)=1) AND ((Emp_spec_1.Spec_ID)=3));` In this example, we are filtering for 1 and 3. It is much easier to visualize in the Query Design Grid. The trick is to bring the Emp_Spec table multiple times. One copy for each criteria. Each one joined to the Employee table by ID.

Comment: These comments are getting kind of involved. If you're answering the question, you should post an answer instead of a long comment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perhaps this is what you have in mind. For test tables [Employees] ...

```
id  first_name  last_name
--  ----------  ---------
 1  Gord        Thompson 
 2  Homer       Simpson  
 3  Hank        Kingsley
```

... and [Emp_spec] ...

```
emp_id  spec_id
------  -------
     1        1
     1        2
     2        1
     3        1
     3        2
```

... the query

```sql
SELECT * FROM Employees
WHERE id IN (SELECT emp_id FROM Emp_spec WHERE spec_id=1)
    AND id IN (SELECT emp_id FROM Emp_spec WHERE spec_id=2)
```

returns

```
id  first_name  last_name
--  ----------  ---------
 1  Gord        Thompson 
 3  Hank        Kingsley
```

Comment: Thank you. It's easier than I expected. One remark though - we need to use DISTNICT to avoid duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it with joins, you would join in one subquery for each spec, which pulls just the rows from Emp_spec that matches a single spec_id. Note Access's strange paren requirements for multiple joins.

```
SELECT Employees.id, Employees.first_name
FROM (Employees
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT employee_id
    FROM Emp_spec
    WHERE spec_id = x_1) specx_1
ON Employees.id = specx_1.employee_id)
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT employee_id
    FROM Emp_spec
    WHERE spec_id = x_2) specx_2
ON Employees.id = specx_2.employee_id
...
```

There's a shortcut you can take, though, but you might consider it to be too kludgey.

```
SELECT Employees.id, Employees.first_name
FROM Employees
INNER JOIN
     (SELECT employee_id
     FROM Emp_spec
     WHERE spec_id IN (x_1, x_2, x_3, ..., x_n)
     GROUP BY employee_id
     HAVING COUNT(*) = n) match_counts
ON Employees.id = match_counts.spec_id
```

The crucial part here is `HAVING COUNT(*) = n`. You only want to get the employees that have `n` records in the Emp_spec table when the table is filtered to just the specs that you want, and where `n` is the number of specs that you're filtering for.

Comment: Interesting. I can see that there's really enough room for creativity here. Just out of curiosity, which of the three working solutions posted here is the most effective? (Not that it really matters in my case.)

Comment: I'd say my second solution would be the most efficient. The one using joins and Gord's solution are about equivalent, except sometimes Access doesn't optimize subqueries in the WHERE clause very well, so if you have a performance problem you might try the join version instead.